# Detecting a duplicate post

Tags: mysql, node.js, spam, spam-prevention

I'm writing something that allows you to post some long form content like blog posts that doesn't require signing up. I want to detect if a post is a duplicate. To be clear, it doesn't have to be perfect, just catch obvious dupes like spammers or bugs where frontend code fails and the user sends two requests to create a post or something.

My initial idea is to remove special characters, whitespace, and some common words like and, but, or etc. and then md5 it. I can then store a "duplicate_hash" or something in the DB.

Then when you go to post it would do a query on the DB for that unique hash. If the hash is found you get a duplicate error.

Would this work very well or is there a better idea for this? We're using Node and MySQL if there happens to be any specific tools for this already out that I'm not finding.

Comment: The problem with using hasing like md5 for something like this is that even though the same input will always produce the same output (hashed), two very similar phrase with the slightest difference will produce a completely different hash.

Comment: @Charles If someone is using a different phrase somewhere, like I mentioned, i don't really care about that. Trying to catch obvious duplicates. i.e. "The cat is fast" vs "That cat is fast" is OK to pass. My use case is bots that post identical posts and people double posting (by accident)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to prevent double submissions by someone hitting the refresh or back button then the messages will be absolutely identical so that's a simple match.

If you goal is to prevent spamming then md5 hash of the message is probably to specific since simply changing a character produces a different hash.

If you want to stick with the md5 hash, you could hash just a chunk of the messages, say from 100 characters to 500 characters. Or lower case everything, remove common words like you said, select the first 25 or 50 words then hash that.